# how to download a bunch of files using JS?

Tags: javascript

I need to download a bunch of files from site zkprb.ru (it's in Russian)
To download one file you nead to enter file code, e.g **02.55.050220** .
So, we'll get link http://zkprb.ru/GetCadastralShemeQuarter.aspx?Quarter=02.55.050220 .
Another step- you need to press href on this page to start downloading.

I wrote such JS code in Chrome Console, but it's still not working correctly:

```
 for (var i=0;i<6;i++)
    { 
    setTimeout(function(i){window.location.href="http://zkprb.ru/GetCadastralShemeQuarter.aspx?Quarter=02.55.05022"+i;
    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload').click();},3000);
    }
```

What's wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: you know that after navigating to a certain page it doesn't just load instantaneously? Your code assumes that immediately after going to a page it will be ready.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. So I am looking for some variant to get around this problem.

Comment: Question - are you doing this for your own website, or are you just trying to get all of this stuff once and then the script will be thrown out?

Comment: Only once. Maybe I'll use it later one more time for "refreshing" data

Comment: OK - assuming you're OK with a simple alternative to using a browser, you've turned this from 'effectively impossible' to 'really easy'.

Comment: So, what should I do? May be not a full guide how to do it, just what to use or to read?